# Density of $\{ \ \{\ln k\} \ \}_{k=1}^{\infty}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

Is this sequence dense in $(0,1)$? I want to say that it is, I think the transcendence of the logarithm function is leading me to believe that it is, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Why do you think it would be dense? It doesn't even have a limit point

Comment: The fractional part of $\ln n$ is dense in $(0,1)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Oh, do you think $\{x\}$ here is denoting the fractional part of $x$? I was assuming it was just using curly braces for the sequence definiiton

Comment: I do not know what OP intends. Was just making an observation related to the problem, since the set $\{\ln k\}$ is clearly not dense in the reals, or the positive reals. But braces **are** sometimes used for fractional part.

Comment: Yeah I realise it was a stupid question now, I was thinking something along the lines of the fractional part but asked the question wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A start: As $n\to\infty$, $\ln(n+1)-\ln n\to 0$, but $\ln n\to\infty$.

*More Detail:* Let $a\in [0,1]$, and let $\epsilon \gt 0$. We show there is an $n$ such that the fractional part pf $\ln n$ differs from $a$ by less than $\epsilon$.

Let $K=K_{\epsilon}$ be a positive integer such that $\frac{1}{K}\lt \epsilon$. Divide the interval $[0,1]$ into $K$ subintervals of equal length. Then $a$ lies in one of these subintervals. We will show that for any subinterval of $[0,1]$ of length $\frac{1}{K}$, there is some $n$ such that the fractional part of $\ln n$ lies in that subinterval.

Note that $\ln(n+1)-\ln n$ approaches $0$ monotonically. So there is an $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$ we have $\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)\lt \frac{1}{K}$.

Let $N^\ast$ be the smallest integer $\gt eN$. We have $\ln N^\ast\gt 1+\ln N$.

As $j$ travels through the integers from $N$ to $N^\ast$, $\ln j$ increases by at least $1$. But since $j\ge N$, we have $\ln(j+1)-\ln j\lt \frac{1}{K}$, so $\ln j$ increases  in steps of length $\lt \frac{1}{K}$. In particular, the fractional part of $\ln j$ enters at least once any subinterval of $[0,1]$ of length $\frac{1}{K}$.

*Remark*: The fact that the logarithm function is transcendental is not used in the argument. The same idea can be used to show that the set of fractional parts of $\sqrt{n}$ is dense in $(0,1)$.

Comment: I don't really understand how asymptotic behaviour helps here. Don't we need to show that for any $x \in (0,1)$ and $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some $K$ such that $|\{\ln K\} - x| < \epsilon$?

Comment: @ZacMurphy: I have added a fair bit of detail. Am somewhat concerned that the $\epsilon$ stuff tends to hide the simple geometry.  If I try to travel a distance $\gt 1$, in hops of varying length but always less than $\epsilon$, and there is a hole of width $\epsilon$ along the way, then I will fall into that hole.

Comment: Ohhh, okay. I get it, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @ZacMurphy: You are welcome.